# Не могу открыть скомпилированную программу .class через командную строку

Tags: java, классы, classpath

Пытался найти ответ в поисковике, что оказалось безуспешно: пробованные способы не работали. Пользуюсь windows 10.

Суть такова: создал простейшую программу в intellij idea с выводом текста. Скомпилировал через консоль, сохранилась в той же папке,что оригинал. При попытке открыть её через командную строку выдаёт следующее (второе изображение). [**введите сюда описание изображения**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UnYe.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Лучше не называйте каталоги и файлы русскими именами. Рано или поздно это приведёт к проблемам. Хотя может дело и не в этом, но может и в этом.

Comment: @CrazyElf скорей всего в этом. Русский параметр из консоли небось в cp866 передается

Comment: Попробовал открыть Main и то же самое.

Comment: Проблема не в кирилличных именах, а в неправильном вызове команды.  Если скомпилированный файл `Циклы.class` содержит метод `public static void main(String ... args) {...}` _действительно_  находится в директории `untitled\src`, его нужно вызвать так: `C:\..\untitled\src>java -cp . Циклы`

Answer (score 0):

1. Создал класс в директории `untitled\src\Циклы.java` (без использования названия пакета `package`)
2. Скомпилировал из консоли (с указанием кодировки UTF8)
3. Можно запускать из той же директории, используя параметр `-cp .`, или вообще без него

```
F:\untitled\src>javac -encoding UTF8 .\Циклы.java

F:\untitled\src>java -cp . Циклы
Итерация №0
Итерация №1
Итерация №2
Итерация №3
Итерация №4
Цикл закончен

F:\untitled\src>F:\untitled\src>javac -encoding UTF8 .\Циклы.java

F:\untitled\src>java -cp . Циклы
Итерация №0
Итерация №1
Итерация №2
Итерация №3
Итерация №4
Цикл закончен

F:\untitled\src>
```